# (Python) Issues with directories that have special characters

Tags: python, windows, directory

- OS: Windows server 03
- Python ver: 2.7

For the code below, its runs fine when I substitute "fuchida@domain.com" with "fuchida". If I use the email format for directory name I get the following error "**WindowsError: [Error 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect:**" . Please let me know what I can do to get this to work, my money is on the "@" symbol fudging things up but I do not know how to resolve it in python so far.

```
import os

def dirListing():
    dirList = os.listdir("C:\\Program Files\home\Server\Logs\fuchida@domain.com")
    for fname in dirList:
        print fname
    return

def main():
    dirListing()

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```

Comment: (per MattH) yep yep escaping or using raw string fixed my headache on this issue

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect problems with your `\` as escape characters. Try this:

```
import os

def dirListing():
    dirList = os.listdir(r"C:\\Program Files\home\Server\Logs\fuchida@domain.com")
    for fname in dirList:
        print fname
    return

def main():
    dirListing()

if __name__ == '__main__':main()
```