# Mercurial: Can't clone project

Tags: mercurial, repository, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree, sourcetree

Me and a friend are woking on a project. We have a repo set on bitbucket, using SourceTree client with mercurial, to update changes.

We have been working this way for over a year, without any issues.

We wanted to grant access to the repository to another friend. He downloaded SourceTree, granted him permission on the bitbucket project, and he starting the cloning process.

After all files where downloaded, he got this message:

```
updating to branch default

abort: file name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect 

Completed with errors, see above.
```

He has all files, but they are all marked as untracked, and when trying to change branches, it says:

```
abort: untracked files in working directory differ from files in requested revision
```

If he goes ahead and remove all untracked files, leaving no file pending, and tries to change branches, no matter what branch he tries to change to, he gets:

```
abort: file name, directory name or volume label syntax is incorrect
```

I have been looking online, and the only explanation I have found online is about some filename having unsupported characters. We double checked, and this is not the case. Both of my friends are running Windows 10, but one work without issies, and the other one gets this error every time.

I also though he was using a path with some folder having a fishy name, but it was not the issue.

Does anyone have any idea of what is happening here?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

The error comes from Python and is passed as an abort in Mercurial. See [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7268618/python-issues-with-directories-that-have-special-characters). Errors from Python are usually caught by mercurial and thrown as an `abort` which is what you are seeing in the output.

Due to the abort Mercurials will not update the "dirstate" which it uses to track what is tracked and what not. This results in things being displayed as non-tracked. Try `hg --traceback update --clean tip` from the commandline inside that repository.

It is hard to say what is going wrong, but I assume the directory he tries to clone to, contains non-ascii characters.

1. Try cloning to a simple directory, e.g.: `"C:\myproject"`
2. Try from the command line: `hg clone YOUR-BITBUCKET-URL`
3. If this still crashes use `hg --traceback clone YOUR-BITBUCKET-URL`. You will see where the error comes from which you can submit as a bug to the Mercurial bugtracker: https://bz.mercurial-scm.org/

Comment: He tried cloning to `C:\test`. Still getting the error. When he is back we will try your answer. I'll update you. Thanks!

Comment: Still getting the same error. We will try with an older mercurial version, and see if it works that way.

Comment: Even using the same version, the error still persists. :/

Comment: This is the result. The bottom line is the error mentioned in spanish: http://i.imgur.com/Vlo9Din.png

Comment: I honestly don't know but to submit a bug report to mercurial. This might very well be a bug. Sorry I can't help you :/